# Separate lines in a text file

Tags: c#

I have a .txt file. Containing INSERT Scripts.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3) INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)

and so on...
```

I want to read this file and output each INSERT statement separately. 
There could be a possibility that a INSERT script is not separated by a new line. it could be continued in the same line. As it can be seen for the last INSERT script.

So I wanted to know if I can read this text file and separate each line whenever I find a new 'INSERT' word ?

Comment: You should show what you've tried... is it enough to read line by line and split on `<space> INSERT`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share your code?

Comment: Your code can be pseudo code or even in another language. Show us some attempt next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sayse gives some hints of the answer. What you can do here is:

- Split on a specific delimiter
- For each value append the delimiter

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XtIRO4)

```
public static void Main()
{
    // search how to read content from a file in C# in case of doubt
    var content = @"INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3) INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)";

    // choose your delimiter
    const string delimiter = "INSERT INTO TABLE ";
    var inserts = content
                  .Split(new []{delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(x => delimiter + x.TrimEnd());
    foreach (var insert in inserts) 
        Console.WriteLine(insert);
}
```

output

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```